# Could someone explain to me the reason for parentheses on types in Objective-C methods?

Tags: objective-c

I am still learning Objective-C but I like to know the "why" behind everything I learn.

I would like to know why an Objective-C method requires that the types are enclosed in parentheses, such as:

```
- (IBAction) myAction: (UIButton *) sender;
```

Instead of:

```
- IBAction myAction: UIButton *sender;
```

I've tried finding answers and thought about it quite a bit but can't seem to see what the reasoning is for.

What troubles me is sometimes I actually forget that the asterisk (`*`) needs to be inside the parentheses, sometimes I accidentally type the following incorrect signature:

```
- (IBAction) myAction: (UIButton) *sender;
```

As to me, this more logically represents the argument is a pointer, not the type.

Comment: This is just syntax rules. Just a convention. Why English uses a and the instead of, for example, ba and shme? Who knows?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha, there is a reason for everything. As [Darren's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13853823/140037) explains where the meaning came about in the context of history of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's C casting syntax:

```
int foo = (int)bar;
```

Think of it as casting the parameters and return value to specific types.

In the very early days of Objective-C return values and parameters defaulted to the `id` type.  So you'd see method declarations like this:

```
-myAction:sender;
```

For numerous reasons it became preferable to strongly type the return value and parameters in Objective-C code, to the point that all return values and parameters are strongly typed, even if they're `id`:

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender;
```

The asterisk is also C syntax.  `UIButton*` is a specific type, different from `UIButton` and `UIButton**`.  You could do this:

```
typedef UIButton* UIButtonRef;
```

and then use `UIButtonRef` instead of `UIButton*`:

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(UIButtonRef)sender;
```

Comment: Darren, this is the exact sort of answer I was after. As being new to the language the history is not really known to me. I thought I understood the asterisk. I did raised [this question](http://tinyurl.com/axybxdq) which made me understand the asterisk is a "pointer variable of type x", i.e. `UIButton* x, y`, both `x` and `y` have different types. So how would `UIButtonRef x, y` be treated? The comma declaration may be bad form and I never use this style, however as I mentioned I do like to understand how things work and why.